# Is there a filtration in discrete time that is not right-continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, filtrations

In discrete time, I've read that a convention for any filtration is to
assume that $\mathcal{F}_{t}=\mathcal{F}_{s} \ \forall s \in [t,t+1[$.

Wouldn't this make $\mathcal{F}_{t+}=\cap_{s>t} \mathcal{F}_s=\mathcal{F}_t$, and so every filtration in discrete time be right-continuous?

Comment: In what context have you encountered this? In discrete-time you normally index your filtration by the natural numbers.

Comment: @JoseAvilez In Elliot and Cohen's Stochastic Calculus And Applications, on page 74, they state that the filtration composed of the  ${\mathcal{F}_{t+}}$ is always right-continuous. I thought this wasn't true for discrete-time, unless an extra condition was added. So, I e-mailed one of the authors , and he replied by saying that convention as usually used.